# How to I re-invoke the promise after the first call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

How can I re-invoke the promise after the first call?

I have this issue where `.then` is executed once only after the first click, you won't get this `console.log("Success!", response);` executed on any click after that. But I need it to **recycle**. Is it possible?

usage:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    get('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random').then(function(response) {
        console.log("Success!", response);
      }, function(error) {
        console.error("Failed!", error);
    });

});
```

promise function:

```
function get(url) {

  // Return a new promise.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      $(".promise").click(function(){

          // do lots of other stuff here...

           // Do the usual XHR stuff
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('GET', url);

            req.onload = function() {
              // This is called even on 404 etc
              // so check the status
              if (req.status == 200) {
                // Resolve the promise with the response text
                resolve(req.response);
              }
              else {
                // Otherwise reject with the status text
                // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
                reject(Error(req.statusText));
              }
            };

            // Handle network errors
            req.onerror = function() {
              reject(Error("Network Error"));
            };

            // Make the request
            req.send();
      });

  });
}
```

html,

```
<a href="#" class="promise">Promise</a>
```

Comment: You have to create a new promise for each click which will require restructuring how your code works.  A given promise can only be used once.  Once it is resolved, it's state can never be changed again.

Comment: You are already using jQuery - why not just do `var get = $.get`? - jQuery's ajax methods already return promises and have done so for years.

Comment: I'm trying to use javascript native stuff often so planning to call ajax without jquery.

Comment: @tealou right, but you're using jQuery _anyway_, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: im going to ditch jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with writing your own promisified `get()` function, which is exactly what jQuery's `$.ajax()` or Angular's `$http` (and others) give you.

All you need to do is rearrange your code slightly such that :

- `get()` is a general purpose utility, not tied to a particular event
- `get()` is called from event handler(s) as required.

```
$(function() {
    function get(url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('GET', url);
            req.onload = function() {
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    resolve(req.response);
                } else {
                    reject(Error(req.statusText));
                }
            };
            req.onerror = function() {
                reject(Error("Network Error"));
            };
            req.send();
        });
    }
    $(".promise").click(function() {
        // do lots of other stuff here...
        get('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random').then(function(response) {
            console.log("Success!", response);
        }, function(error) {
            console.error("Failed!", error);
        });
    });
});
```

All I've done here is move your lines of code into a different order.

Comment: thanks. yes you are right. I must move the click event outside and the problem is solved.  thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in my comment, a promise can only be used once.  Once it is resolved or rejected, it's state is set forever and it will never call the existing `.then()` handlers again.  So, you can't use a promise for something that you want called each time an event occurs.  You're probably back to callbacks for that like this which seems perfectly appropriate for this situation:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    get('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random', function(response) {
        console.log("Success!", response);
      }, function(error) {
        console.error("Failed!", error);
    });

});

function get(url, success, fail) {

    $(".promise").click(function(){

      // do lots of other stuff here...

       // Do the usual XHR stuff
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', url);

        req.onload = function() {
          // This is called even on 404 etc
          // so check the status
          if (req.status == 200) {
            // Resolve the promise with the response text
            success(req.response);
          }
          else {
            // Otherwise reject with the status text
            // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
            fail(Error(req.statusText));
          }
        };

        // Handle network errors
        req.onerror = function() {
          fail(Error("Network Error"));
        };

        // Make the request
        req.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i think i will just have to move the click event outside the function - just as Roamer-1888 suggests.

Comment: @tealou - If you only call `get()` once at initialization, then you don't have to move the click handler outside the function because what the function does is install the click handler and set up callbacks.  But, if you intend to use that function more than once or in more than one circumstance, then it needs to be refactored so you can reuse pieces of it better.